# Download image from URL with wget and change the file name automatically

Tags: command-line, wget

I want to download all the images from an URL using `wget` and set the name of output file based on the url.

For example, if I download this picture:

```
wget https://www.electrictoolbox.com/images/icons/linux-bsd.gif
```

The filename will be `linux-bsd.gif` but I want it to be `images_icons_linux-bsd.gif`

I would like it to be automated.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
wget --output-document=images_icons_linux-bsd.gif https://www.electrictoolbox.com/images/icons/linux-bsd.gif
```

...all in one line.

Answer (score 3):

#### Finding all images of a website

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442841/download-images-from-website), you can do so with the following:

```
# get all pages
curl 'http://domain.com/id/[1-151468]' -o '#1.html'

# get all images
grep -oh 'http://pics.domain.com/pics/original/.*jpg' *.html >urls.txt

# download all images
sort -u urls.txt | wget -i-
```

#### Getting the Image

Here's a bash script, taking a URL as the first parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=`echo $1 | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed 's/https:__[a-z\.]\+_//g'`
wget -O $name $1
```

It may not work with some URLs, just so you know.